# String cannot be of zero length error

Tags: sql, vb.net, ssis

I have a Visual Basic script when I run that

```
Dim area As String = Row.Area.Substring(0, Row.Area.IndexOf("-") + 1)
Row.Area = Row.Area.Replace(area, "")
```

I am getting this error:

> System.ArgumentException: String cannot be of zero length.Parameter name: oldValue at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ScriptComponentHost.HandleUserException(Exception e) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ScriptComponentHost.ProcessInput(Int32 inputID, PipelineBuffer buffer) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ManagedComponentHost.HostProcessInput(IDTSManagedComponentWrapper100 wrapper, Int32 inputID, IDTSBuffer100 pDTSBuffer, IntPtr

Comment: Looks like VB to me, not C#...

Comment: Is that complete call stack? It doesn't look like anything you are doing is calling into sql server?

Comment: Thats the one giving error

Comment: It seems like oldValue can't be empty. Did you check the value of oldValue and see how it is generated? Nothing in your code is showing oldValue

Comment: Is this a script running in an SSIS package? This is way too little information to go on and the code doesn't match the error. Please update with more information.

Comment: Its a script task in ssis, all other row has 03-Napoleon, Norvell, Columbia T, there is a number and hyphen except for one row

Comment: @JacobH that's the error message returned by Replace if the first value is empty..

Comment: Your error messages don't match the code you posted. However as a general programing note, this: "Row.Area.IndexOf("-") + 1)" is assuming a lot. If Row.Area is empty or doesn't contain a "-" or the dash is the last character, your code will fail. Check the string length before assuming +1 is OK, and check that the "-" is found before doing a substring on it. This applies to any programming you're going anywhere. You can't just assume that your string will exist or be big enough or contain what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if the area *contains* a hyphen. Otherwise `Row.Area.Substring(0, Row.Area.IndexOf("-") + 1)` will return **an empty string**, and passing the empty string to `Replace` is what is causing the error.

So (and please excuse any invalid VB.Net)

```
If Row.Area.Contains("-") Then
    Dim area As String = Row.Area.Substring(0, Row.Area.IndexOf("-") + 1)
    Row.Area = Row.Area.Replace(area, "")
End If
```